# Invite friends to event php api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Well, i am stucked now. I got this error everytime i try to invite users to group. 
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) thrown in /home/xxx/public_html/konkurrence/src/base_facebook.php on line 1133

$id is ex: 
     531559617,578399497,597219863,611583892,615217497,615862203,622354685,641989790,642609101,664099777,684181267,685978537,688529379,702356299,731199845,735261307,747864007,753442688,757574019,757617533,773399820,805573671,824600788,827164118,899525726

my scope is: read_friendlists,user_likes,create_event,user_events,friends_events,offline_access

PS: Ofcouse facebook and $eventid is set etc.

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['friends'] ) ) :

foreach ( $_GET as $l => $fis ) {
   $e.= $l . "=".$fis."&";
}
$i=0;
foreach ( $_POST['friends'] as $ids ) {
   if ( $i>48 && $user == $ids) :
   else:
       $id.=$ids . ",";
       $i=$i+1;
   endif;
}
$id = substr_replace($id ,"",-1);


echo $facebook->api($event_id . "/invited",'POST', array("users" => $id));

endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/560/

Answer (score 0):

The error #200 is a permissions error which you have not caught via something such as

```
try {
    echo $facebook->api($event_id . "/invited",'POST', array("users" => $id));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
}
```

You might also want to to check to see whether the currently authenticated user has RSVP set for the event before the user invites friends. You cannot invite users to events you yourself have not RSVP'd for.

```
/EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "You cannot invite users to events you yourself have not RSVP'd for."

Comment: @user1743233 you (or the current user) needs to click "Attending" before you can invite others.